# Is this another example of bad audit question?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

[Shell behavior difference with empty parameter in heredocument](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/34146042)

To me, it was clear-cut that there were multiple questions.  It was allowed in the past, but surely according to the current guidelines, I was right to flag it as **Multiple Questions**.

I was not distracted.  I was so sure that I did not even look at the original question.  I could just pretend to edit all of them, but that defeats the purpose of the audit.

Comment: The system only knows how others have treated the post. Likely it was not closed or downvoted because although there are indeed 2 question marks they really do together amount to just "What documentation-justified explanations are there for this behavior?" But having 2 questions makes it a misleading review.

Answer (score 11):

There are indeed two question marks:

> What explanations are there [...]?
>
> Is it documented why [...]?

But those are about the exact same observed behavior. These are not two different questions. They ask in fact exactly the same, just in different phrasing.

Comment: Agreed - and to the extent that they differ, they are _so_ closely related as to be essentially different aspects of one focused question (what are the explanations, and does the documentation have anything to say on the matter?).