# Yet more bad review audits, where's the option to disagree already?

Tags: feature-request, disputed-review-audits

I know this is an old complaint that will get closed as a duplicate. I've posted about it myself in the past.

I don't even care about the suspension, it's only for two days.

I've downvoted both answers after failing these, which should hopefully prevent them from being used in future audits ([though maybe not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424116/how-is-this-question-about-programming-surely-it-is-not-a-good-audit-question?cb=1#comment953560_424116))

**But there *really* needs to be some option other than "I understand" on bad review audits.**

FWIW, I was suspended for choosing to "share feedback" on these two audits:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/34196819
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/34210810

> We suspect that you are not actually reviewing the tasks

No, I *am*. They're just mediocre answers that could benefit from an explanation or reference. Adding a comment, canned or otherwise, is a reasonable action.

I get it: I'm a developer. I know it takes effort to design, implement, test, and support new features. And if there's an easy way to challenge bad audits, we need people to review and evaluate the challenges, and somehow feed that back into the system...

But seriously, let's get an "I disagree with this audit because _________" option, please.

Comment: Unrelated to this feature request I cleared the auto-suspension. Share Feedback is certainly reasonable for either or both of these review tasks, particularly the first.

Comment: Wasn't there a review strike in the past to increase the pressure on SO inc. to fix some issues with the review process? Maybe it is time to think about that option now as well.

Comment: I agree with this. But with the post you gave, there is another problem: it have been asked for Close vote but invalidated before beeing choosed as audit. I think that it should prevent it to be taken as the system could not be sure it's a good one

Comment: @Tom Also, going to the post review link shows the current version of the post, not the version that was reviewed.

Comment: Related on MSE: [Add an "I don't understand" option for review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188780/997587)

Comment: I'm sure that feature would be abused to the high heavens, but it is time the pain is shared a little more.

Comment: @tom review strike will only result in less reviews done, it won't result in anyone caring more. Push comes to shove, the site keeps ticking whether reviews are done or not.

Comment: @Gimby That the site won't crumble is obvious, but we don't have any other leverage, other then not continue doing stuff for free so they can keep earning their salaries while doing nothing in return.